# creating formulas when data is missing - how to use another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm not an excel pro so use basic language... :)

I've inherited a sheet which has been filled in manually so far but want to at least bring some cells into the 21st century.

```
D1 =TODAY()

F4: start date (manual input, short date)

G4:  end date (manual input, short date)

H4 =DATEDIF(F4,G4,"m")

I4 =@IFS(H4>12,"12+ Months",H4>=6,"6-12 Months",H4>=3,"3-6 Months",H4>0,"0-3 Months")
```

**Problem** -

I need to know what `I4` is 'now' if it doesn't have an end date but, if G4 is blank, then I get #NUM! in both `H4` and `I4`

How can use '`today()` as an alternate if `G4` is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that in H4 actually, replacing G4 with an `IF` condition

- if G4 is blank ---> `ISBLANK(G4)`
- then use today ---> `today()`
- else use G4

---

```
 H4 = DATEDIF(F4,IF(ISBLANK(G4),today(),G4) ,"m")
```

Comment: cheers!!!  but...if F4 AND G4 are empty, what do i need to add to keep H4 blank?

Comment: @ladyV if the answer helped, can you please accept (green tick) the answer and upvote?

Comment: have done that... but got this message...thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.